# Issue with copying multiple files using Power automate

Tags: power-automate, file-system

I have a requirement to copy modified files from SharePoint to shared network path. When i execute this using Power automate in a loop, first file content is being used for other files and leading to wrong file creation. I have tried to add delay in loop and reset file identifier string but still same issue is observed.This behavior is inconsistent, sometime it works fine.

Please let me know how to handle this issue. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Are the files are in a Library or in a List as Attachments? Within your loop, are you fetching each **file's content** by using [Get file content] and passing [identifer]? I've not noticed this issue though. If you can post your flow, I can take a look into it.

Comment: I am performing this on Library. I have posted same query along with image on below link https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Issue-with-copying-multiple-files-using-Power-automate/m-p/873822#M21911

Comment: Logically, not seeing any issue. Can you check [Identifier] and [File Name with Path] in the flow running history? Do they look different in the [Apply to each]? Another thing, you may not need [Parse JSON] action here, you could directly use **[Value]** from [Get file (properties only)] in [Apply to each].

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved after disabling Concurrency level in Apply each action

[image]